# Check for existing values with if in foreach?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have array with already existing values:

```
$existingValues = array();
```

now i get new values in xml file (is a import script) but i have to avoid insert of already existing values, my question is, how can i do a if check in foreach where i list all new values from xml?

```
$i = 1;

foreach($node->children() as $child) :
    $attribute2 = $child->attributes();
    $productcode = $attribute2['sku'];
    $productvariant = $attribute2['variantid'];
    $productprice = $attribute2['price'];

    if ($attribute2['sku']) :
        echo $productcode . ' - ' . $productvariant . '<br>';
    endif;

    $i++;      
endforeach;
```

I tried with `in_array()`  but it's not correct.

Comment: How do you identify elements? I can see that every element has some fields (`sku`, `variantid`, `price`). What is the id of each element? `sku` maybe?

Comment: Ahh sorry, yes i have to check sku, if sku from array and sku from xml is the same then ignore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array wich stores the products and test if the current product is already in the array:

```
$i = 1;
$products = array();

foreach($node->children() as $child) :
    $attribute2 = $child->attributes();
    $productcode = $attribute2['sku'];
    $productvariant = $attribute2['variantid'];
    $productprice = $attribute2['price'];

    if ($attribute2['sku'] && !in_array($productcode, $products)) :
        echo $productcode . ' - ' . $productvariant . '<br>';
    endif;

    $products[] = $productcode;

    $i++;      
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `$existingSKU` array, extracting `sku` from existing elements. Then you can compare current `sku` with existing, and if not present, you can add element to existing.

```
// build existing sku array
$existingSKU = array();
foreach($existingValues as $value)
{
    array_push($existingSKU, $value['sku']);
}

// add element to existing, if not present
foreach($node->children() as $child)
{
    $attribute2 = $child->attributes();

    if(!in_array($attribute2['sku'], $existingSKU))
    {
       array_push($existingValues, $attribute2);
    }
}
```

Since you don't use it, you can remove `$i`.